# Matching RGB image with point cloud

Tags: matlab, image-processing, point-clouds

I have an RGB image and a point cloud acquired by LIDAR. 
In the RGB image I detect a feature, let's say a circle. 
I want to use this circle as a ROI in my 3d point cloud. 
How can I do that? I was thinking to produce a 3d point cloud from the RGB image through the camera parameters and then match the 2 with icp algorithm. 
  The problem's that on the moment I produce  the point cloud from the 2D image, my coordinates system change, so I don't know anymore the position of my circle. 
To perform 3d reconstruction I use triangulateMultiview function

Comment: How can a circle define a 3D ROI ?

Comment: i use zmax and zmin of the object for the 3th direction

Comment: Is the RGB image registered with the point cloud ?

Comment: There are 2 point cloud. Lidar_pointcloud which is not registered.
Photogrammetry_pointcloud, generated by photogrammetry so it could be registered

Comment: Hem, registration is one wrt the other. A point cloud cannot be registered in the absolute.

Comment: so how i could pass the info of the roi to the 3d point cloud? 
There is a way to obtain the matrix the algorithm use to convert the coordinates of the circle?

Comment: Show samples, the question is pretty vague.

Comment: My object is a box with a hole. I am able to detect the position of the hole in my 2D rgb picture because it has a circulare shape .  
So, i know the position of the hole, in my picture. 
Of the box, I have even the Lidar point cloud. I would like to find the position of the hole in the point cloud, by coupling the info from the RGB and the point cloud. 
I am trying to do that, producing a second pt cloud using photogrammetry. The problem is: when thanks to photogrammetry I pass to the 3d point cloud, how do I keep the information about the position of the hole

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking to produce a 3d point cloud from the RGB image through the camera parameters and then match the 2 with icp algorithm. 
-> this would not work and not efficient.

Actually, there is a much better way. Assuming that you know the extrinsic between the camera and lidar, any circle(or ellipse) on the image can be extended into a 3d cone using the camera intrinsic and by selecting the points within the cone you can do the ROI operation.

Let's say you can define an ellipse on your image plane by detecting and finding the parameters of an ellipse equation. The ellipse equation can be extended into the quadric(cone) equation which representing the 3D cone. Now the only thing left is testing if your 3d point is within the cone by putting the cone equation.

This is a mathematically little bit complicated problem if you are not comfortable with camera model or quadric equation.

Comment: So what you are saying, it's to perform a 3d reconstruction of the ellipse, and than use the rotation matrix Camera-->Lidar to pass the ROI and use it on point cloud. 
The problem is that the lidar work rotating around the object, acquiring the object step by step, while the camera is one shot. 
Even if I would know the position of the camera and the orientation respect to the object, it miss the rotation matrix, that is what i wanted to gain by icp...

Comment: You mean the camera and LiDAR is not rigidly attached?